# Jboss 6 I am trying to deploy restfull webservices on server but faced exception

Tags: java, rest, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy restfull webservices on jboss6 but failed.
Exception is below here.

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "copl.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"copl.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"copl.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"copl.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module \"deployment.copl.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module \"deployment.copl.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`** class is missing. Please find the jar containing this class and add it in jboss6 standalone/lib/ext folder. If issue not fixed then add it in your project lib folder (runtime libraries).

Comment: I have download the jar for (com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer) from this URL
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomsunjerseyjerseyserver140jar.htm

17:23:22,279 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig in Module "deployment.copl.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig (Module "deployment.copl.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

Comment: which jar file you are using? I think you have download some some other jar file causing problem.. plz try with this jar file: jersey-bundle-1.2

Comment: I have put the jersey-bundle-1.2 
now I am facing this exception:

ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."copl.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."copl.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "copl.war"

Comment: Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig

Comment: Remove these two lines from standalone-full.xml
1- <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
2- <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>

Comment: I have removed above lines from standlone-full.xml now I am facing this exception:
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011030: Could not configure component ServiceBean
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:94)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]

Comment: JBAS014227: EJB ServiceBean of type au.com.copl.bean.ServiceBean must have public default constructor

Comment: add the code public ServiceBean(){} in your ServiceBean.java class :)